# I am trying to make a specific element hide when certain cookie is present (JS)

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have this little static page. I have some sub pages that contains information about certain events. I have added a little exclamation mark to the top left of that element and I want that only to be present if the user doesn't have visited pages. And I thought this was easier to do with cookies. So when the user clicks element the first time this cookie is added and it will add `display: none` to that certain element. I tried this and when I did the change to include the code below. And it removed the element before adding the cookie. Is there anyone that can help me with the issue or tell me a better way to do it?

```
function Visited2018() {
  document.cookie = "Visited 2018 = true"
}

function Visited2019() {
  document.cookie = "Visited 2019 = true"
}

function NewInformation() {
  const cookieValue = document.cookie.split(';')
   if(cookieValue[0] = "Visited 2018 = true"){
      document.getElementById("2018").style.display = "none";
    }
   if(cookieValue[1] = "Visited 2019 = true"){
      document.getElementById("2019").style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("2018").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("2019").style.display = "block";
      console.log("Not visited any of the new pages")
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I decided to go with Local Storage :)

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you are [**assigning values**](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-operators-conditionals-functions/#assignmentoperators) in your `if` clauses? 

Also, take a look at this [JavaScript Cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Comment: I am now. Just fixed it and it is now giving not removing the element when the cookie is present :)

Comment: This isn't very clear nor reproducible, take a look at how to ask a question at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I would gladly try to help if I can run your code instead of figuring it out on my own.

Comment: I decided to go with Localstorage. Found out it was simpler :)